# Plot Confidence Ellipses for Multiple Factor Analysis

Tags: r, statistics, ellipse

I'm trying to plot ellipses with the function http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.foodqual.2012.04.010 for the results of a Multiple Factor Analysis however I can't get the individual ellipses. For this I am trying to use the example of the FactoMineR package. If anyone can help me identify the error I would be very grateful.

```
library(FactoMineR)

data(wine)
res <- MFA(wine, group=c(2,5,3,10,9,2), type=c("n",rep("s",5)),
    ncp=5, name.group=c("orig","olf","vis","olfag","gust","ens"),
    num.group.sup=c(1,6))

Article function:
MFAconf = function(MFAresob, axes = c(1,2)){
  if (!require("FactoMineR")) install.packages("FactoMineR");
  library("FactoMineR")
  # The number of samples (n)
  n = dim(MFAresob$ind$coord)[1]
  # The number of groups of variables (m)
  m = dim(MFAresob$group$coord)[1]
  # Creating a new data frame with one row for each sample’s assiociated MFA group of variables.
  CATnames <- vector(mode="character", length = n*m)
  for (j in 1:n){CATnames[(((j-1)*m)+1):(j*m)] <- dimnames(MFAresob$ind$coord[order(row.names(MFAresob$ind$coord)),])[[1]][j]}
  PartielDim <- cbind.data.frame(names = CATnames,MFAresob$ind$coord.partiel)
  PartielDim$names = as.factor(PartielDim$names)
  
  # Bootstrapping the new data frame
  Boot <- simule(PartielDim, nb.simul = 500)
  # Creating ellipses around 95% of the bootstrapped means
  EllipCoord <- coord.ellipse(Boot$simul, level.conf = 0.95, bary = FALSE, axes=axes, npoint = 100)
  #Plotting the ellipses
  plot.MFA(MFAresob, choix = "ind",title ="", axes = axes,  ellipse = EllipCoord,ellipse.par = NULL)
}

#Applying the function to the results for MFA:

MFAconf(MFAresob = res)
```